# Admob reactivate account has no checkbox

Tags: admob

On my Admob account, it says that, "AdMob account inactive Your AdMob account has been inactive for over 5 months. Accounts that haven't served ads for 6 months will be automatically deactivated." Then a [Learn More](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/10491752?hl=en) button. It says there that there is a checkbox but it is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Same here, did you get any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message I have received is just a warning. After I exceeded the 6 months, that's the time that I can click the checkbox. As long as it won't appear means your AdMob is still active.